# Is it possible to set Never expire for IE mode on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, uipath

Currently I'm developing RPA with UiPath to automate tasks in my internal website that requires only IE for compatibility.
And we can use only Microsoft Edge browser with set IE mode at this time, since my company doesn't allow to install IE browser from now.
Is it possible to set Never expire for IE mode on Microsoft Edge?
[image]

Comment: Do you actually need to test for IE compatibility? If so, **why?** (no seriously, I want to know)

Comment: @Dai, I need to deploy program to production for long term. It's Unattended robot and I don't want to set IE mode again in every next 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure the enterprise mode site list using the group policy then it will never expire and could help you overcome the 30 days limit when you add the site to IE mode manually.

You could ask the IT department in your company to help you set up the group policies for the Edge browser to configure the IE mode and sitelist.

Below are the detailed steps.

I assume that you already have the latest [MS Edge policy template](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download) installed. If not, you could refer to the steps from [Configure Microsoft Edge policy settings on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge).

1. You need to enable the policy [Configure Internet Explorer integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#configure-internet-explorer-integration) and set it to **IEmode**.
2. After that you need to create an [Enterprise site list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/what-is-enterprise-mode#site-list-xml-file) XML file. You could use the [Enterprise mode site list manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49974) tool to create the site list.
3. Then you need to set the policy [Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list) and pass the site list.xml file as a parameter.
4. Force update the group policy by running the **gpupdate /force** command in the CMD.
5. You could try to launch the MS Edge browser and try to visit the legacy site, it should launched in the IE-mode.

Let us know if you have further questions or you face any difficulty configuring the IE mode. I will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: It's working on my Microsoft Edge Version 104.0.1293.63 (Official build) (64-bit). Thank you very much.